# getting null when trying to find parent of a child record in one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm a newbie to Laravel. I'm trying to make an application where notices and files models has one to many relationship in between them.
noticesAlter table contain notice_subject, additional_data, created_at, updated_at
and files table contain filename, notice_id, created_at, updated_at.
where notice_id is the foreign key in files table that references 'id' in 'noticesAlter' table

Here are my models

```
class noticesAlter extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'noticesalter';
    protected $fillable = ['notice_subject', 'filename', 'additional_details'];
    public function Files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Files', 'notice_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Files extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'files';
    protected $fillable = ['notice_id', 'filename'];
    public function noticesAlter()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\noticesAlter', 'notice_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I try to find files of a notice through tinker with id = 29, I get the desired result i.e. all my files that have notice_id = 29 as foreign key.
[First Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCs6K.png)
As you can see in the image that I get a file with id=45 and notice_id = 29.

But When I try to find the parent notice of the same file, I get a null object and this
[Second Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KEAD.png)
I have no idea what wrong am I doing? Why I'm not getting the parent notice record.

Answer (score 1):

Your `noticesAlter()` method is not returning anything (missing the `return` keyword). This is why your error says you're trying to call `get()` on `null`, because `noticesAlter()` returns `null` if nothing is returned.

Update your method to return the relationship:

```
public function noticesAlter()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\noticesAlter', 'notice_id', 'id');
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.
That was really a stupid thing that I was doing.
Thanks for helping me out @patricus